# Htaccess Removing index.php? from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When i have a website configured with SSL, when accessing the website with HTTPS:// everything works fine, but when i do it with HTTP i get 'index.php?' in the end of URL :  https://domaine.com/index.php?/.

Here is my HTACESS :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules as this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or clear your browser cache completely before testing.

Comment: i got as a result domain.com/?/

Answer (score 0):

The following forces any http request to be rewritten using https. For example, the following code forces a request to http://example.com to load https://example.com. It also forces directly linked resources (images, css, etc.) to use https.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

If this isn't working for you, first check your line endings. Copy/paste from your web browser into a text editor may not work right, so after pasting into your text editor you should delete each line break and add it back in (line break = return key).